VueJS form return undefined when form field doesn't have a value
I have an issue when using yup in VueJS. I created a form for submitting data. when submit data, if the value is not mentioned it returns as undefined. I want to remove undefined and set a default value to that. How can I do that?
This is a snapshot of the console:

And here is the code:
<template>
  <div class="flex items-center justify-center p-6">
    <div class="container max-w-screen-lg mx-auto">
      <div>
        <div class="p-4 px-4 mb-6 rounded shadow-lg card md:p-8">
          <div class="grid grid-cols-1 text-sm lg:grid-cols-3">
            <div class="">
              <p>Please fill out all the fields.</p>
            </div>

            <div class="lg:col-span-2">
              <Form @submit="handleSave" :validation-schema="schema" class="mt-7">
                <div class="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                  <label class="formLabel">First Heading</label>
                  <Field type="text" name="headingFirst" class="formFeild" as="textarea" placeholder="First Heading"/>
                  <ErrorMessage name="headingFirst" class="error-feedback" />
                </div>
                <div class="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                  <label class="formLabel">Second Heading</label>
                  <Field type="text" name="headingLast" class="formFeild" as="textarea" placeholder="Second Heading" />
                  <ErrorMessage name="headingLast" class="error-feedback" />
                </div>
                <div class="relative z-0 w-full mb-6 group">
                  <label class="formLabel">Description</label>
                  <Field type="text" name="description" class="formFeild" as="textarea" rows="5" placeholder="Description" />
                  <ErrorMessage name="description" class="error-feedback" />
                </div>

                <div class="flex-row">
                  <button type="submit" class="button_save">
                    Save
                  </button>
                </div>
              </Form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Form, Field, ErrorMessage } from "vee-validate";
import * as yup from "yup";

export default {
  components: {
    Form,
    Field,
    ErrorMessage,
  },
  data() {
    const schema = yup.object().shape({
      headingFirst: yup.string().typeError("Enter or Select Valid Data").required("This is required!").max(50, "Must be maximum 50 characters!"),
      headingLast: yup.string().typeError("Enter or Select Valid Data").max(50, "Must be maximum 50 characters!"),
      description: yup.string().typeError("Enter or Select Valid Data").max(600, "Must be maximum 600 characters!"),
    });

    return {
      id:'',
      schema,
    };
  },
  computed: {
    loggedIn() {
      return this.$store.state.auth.status.loggedIn;
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.id = this.$route.params.id;
  },
  methods: {
    handleSave(data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
  },
};
</script>

I tried several ways by doing below changes to yup schema. But it doesn't work for me.
 const schema = yup.object().shape({
          headingFirst: yup.string().typeError("Enter or Select Valid Data").required("This is required!").max(50, "Must be maximum 50 characters!").default("N/A"),
          headingLast: yup.string().typeError("Enter or Select Valid Data").max(50, "Must be maximum 50 characters!").default("N/A"),
          description: yup.string().typeError("Enter or Select Valid Data").max(600, "Must be maximum 600 characters!").default("N/A"),
        });

